# Jquery. Как получить количество видимых дочерних элементов родительского блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть меню выпадашка, где есть пункты одного типа, и пункты другого, примерно в таком виде каждый пункт:

```
<li>
Категория
    <ul>
         <li class="type1">Пункт тип 1</li>
         <li class="type2">Пункт тип 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

И я поставил 2 кнопки, чтобы каждая из них скрывала один из типов полей. Но есть пункты в которых только один тип, и хотелось бы чтобы если видимые дочерние пункты у родительского пункта отсутствуют, то и он бы скрывался. Как этого можно добится в jquery?

Comment: Т.е. если у "Категория" нет подкатегорий - его спрятать, так?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, не совсем, если подкатегории скрыты, то спрятать

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать родительским li какой-то класс и проверять, есть ли у них дочерние ul'ы. Если нет, скрывать:

```js
$('.parent').each(function(){
  if($(this).children('ul').size() == 0) {
     $(this).css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="parent">
Категория 1
    <ul>
         <li class="type1">Пункт тип 1</li>
         <li class="type2">Пункт тип 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="parent">
Категория 2
    <ul>
         <li class="type1">Пункт тип 1</li>
         <li class="type2">Пункт тип 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="parent">
Категория 3
    
</li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```